# How to set Cronjob using Crontab command from 10.00 am to 6:45 pm at 15 min interval

Tags: linux, unix, cron, cronexpression

I have a process which should be set at cronjob from 10:00am till 6:45 pm at 15 min interval every day .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'd be like this:

```
*/15 10-18 * * * command...
```

Comment: yeah but i need till 6:45 pm ..is there any other way to try this .please suggest

Comment: I edited my answer, try it out, it may just work.  :)  If not, you'll need to use multiple similar jobs to get all the times you want.